# C++ functions and methods style

Tags: c++

For example, we have a function and its result is an array. I often see something like this:

```
void func(some_args, result_array){//some code//}
```

So as you can see the function does not return the array and we pass it as an argument.

The second case looks like this:

```
float* func(some_args){ //some code// return result_array;}
```

Is there any convention about that or this is just about personal preferences? Personally I noticed that the second declaration, which returns an array, is very rare. Are there any reasons for that?

**UPD**: I'm sorry for being imprecise. Of course, I implied a pointer to an array in the second case.

Comment: The second case ***does not*** return an array -- it returns a pointer.  These are not at all the same thing.  Arrays cannot be returned from functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger arrays cannot be returned from functions, but `std::array`s can be returned. I am always a bit confused about people insisting that one cannot return an array in C++. Either I am missing something crucial or `std::array` should get more advertised

Comment: C/C++ function don't return arguments, they leave them unchanged. Pointer arguments allow to change the value(s) at the pointed-to address, but the pointer itself remains unchanged.

Comment: @tobi303, `std::array` is a class containing an actual array and providing array-like properties.  Instances are "arrays" only in an STL-based, "that's the class's name" sense, not in the *bona fide* C++-language sense that people use when they say that arrays cannot be returned by functions.  The declaration of a *real* array has this general form: `float my_array[8];`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger would you not agree, that using a `std::array` is a way to return an array from a function? I mean I agree that one cannot return a naked array, but already putting it inside a struct makes it possible.

Comment: @tobi303, when anyone, including me, says that arrays cannot be returned from functions, they mean that C++-language arrays cannot be the declared return type of a function or method. `std::array` has no bearing on that at all.  My apologies if my imprecision confused you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am just a bit pedantic sometimes about using the right words. I mean to someone who knows that "array" refers to arrays in the strict C++ sense you dont have to explain that it cannot be returned from a function, but anybody else might get the impression that there is absolutely no way to get an array out of a function (via return). However, I think on the facts we completely agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is ownership.

```
void func(some_args, float*);
```

vs

```
float* func(some_args);
```

In the first form, it's very clear who is responsible for providing the memory for the array. In the second cause there is ambiguity: does the function you called own the memory or is it being transferred to you. Who is responsible for `delete`[]ing it?

```
char* s = strdup("hello");
// I have to remember to 'free()' what was strdup'd
// but what if I think "this is C++" and delete[] it?
```

-- Edit --

This may have contributed in part to the evolution of C++11s smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`), so the better option than the two discussed would be the use of one of those.

std::unique_ptr func(some_args);

This explicitly states "I'll return you a thing that you become responsible for".

Comment: It isn't *that* clear who is in charge of providing the memory in the first example because the signature is incomplete.

Comment: @juanchopanza how is the signature incomplete? variable names aren't required for a *signature* to be complete.

Comment: The parameters have no type.

Comment: @juanchopanza They have type, they don't have names, and I don't provide definition of the types. But if you want, `using some_args = int; using pointer_to_a_thing_you_own = void;`.

Comment: OK then.  `result_array` could be reference to pointer, and the first function could be in charge of allocating memory.

Comment: Returning std::unique_ptr<foo> is a good way of ordering the caller to deal with the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are "second-class" citizens in the C++ type system.

What you should do instead is returning a container (e.g. an `std::vector`) as those are more uniformly handled by the language.

The problems of arrays is that

- They in most cases "decay" into a pointer to the first element, losing the size information
- The size of an array is a compile-time constant

`std::vector` is a thin wrapper around a dynamically allocated array but can be passed to functions or manipulated like any other value type and also the size is a run-time value. Of course there is no golden rule that you can apply always... but most often when in C you use an array in C++ you use an `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any convention about that

Yes, there is a 'convention' for this issue.

Most professional environments will have a coding standard.  There will also be peer reviews and (maybe) static analyzers to detect and enforce the standard.

As an example, the "Google C++ Style Guide" (guess how easy it is to find), identifies parameter ordering:

> When defining a function, parameter order is: inputs, then outputs.
>
> Parameters to C/C++ functions are either input to the function, output
>   from the function, or both. Input parameters are usually values or
>   const references, while output and input/output parameters will be
>   non-const pointers. When ordering function parameters, put all
>   input-only parameters before any output parameters. In particular, do
>   not add new parameters to the end of the function just because they
>   are new; place new input-only parameters before the output parameters.
>
> This is not a hard-and-fast rule. Parameters that are both input and
>   output (often classes/structs) muddy the waters, and, as always,
>   consistency with related functions may require you to bend the rule.

I would also add that a lot of code has been written that might not conform to this guide.  My last gig insisted coders make their code match any related code ... not a 'crystal clear' goal there.

---

You present your first case improperly:

```
void func(some_args, result_array){//some code//}
```

So let me try a presentation with more hints:

The convention discussed by the Google C++ Style Guide might better be presented as

```
void func(T1 argIn1, 
          T2 argIn2, 
          const T3& argIn3,
          std::vector<T4>& argOut4);
```

So argIn1 and argIn2 are passed-by-value into func, and clearly inputs.

argIn3 is const ref, and also an input.  This is how to pass large inputs to the function without incurring the cost of the copy.

argOut4 is passed by non-constant-reference, and, in this case, certainly output, but might be considered input and output.

---

There are plenty of code examples (i.e. linux api, etc) where the function returns something.  You can make your own count and decide if any result applies to your efforts.  I can find plenty (such as memcmp) where the return value is the important result, but I have feeling (that I have not confirmed) that most (or perhaps more) historic functions return a status ... perhaps 0 when success, or -1 when error and a value in errno to describe.

Thus, these days, I prefer to return std::string.  When the return size() is 0, no error occurred, else, the error description is captured in the string.

---

Your second case is also stated poorly.  functions and methods can only return 1 thing ... it could a class or struct and filled with information, but the function semantics can only return a single item.

Following the style guide (any coding standard) is a good thing.  I have followed several parts of the Google Style guide for several years now.  It has merged easily with my standard practice.